# Sorting values in one column that contains NAs by the order of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1':['A_2','A_1','A_3','A_4','A_6','A_5','A_8','A_7'],
'col2':['NaN','A_2','A_3','A_4','A_5','NaN','A_1','A_6']}, orient='index').T
```

I want to change the order of the second column, `col2` and change it so the items that are the same in both columns match up like this:

```
       col1     col2
   0    A_2     A_2
   1    A_1     A_1
   2    A_3     A_3
   3    A_4     A_4
   4    A_6     A_6
   5    A_5     A_5
   6    A_7     NaN
   7    A_8     NaN
```

Trying :   `df.iloc[:,1].sort_values(df.iloc[:,0])` just returns an error message about unhashable series

Suppose now that there are two dataframes:

df1:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A_2','A_1','A_3','A_4','A_6','A_5','A_8','A_7'],
'col2':[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0], 'col3':[1,6,7,5,4,3,9,8]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'N1':['NaN','A_2','A_3','A_4','A_5','NaN','A_1','A_6'],
             'N2':['NaN',0,1,2,3,'NaN',0,1], 'N3':['NaN',0,0,0,0,'NaN',0,0]})
```

And I want to sort like above but this time, all columns and rows in `df2`:

output:

```
N1    N2    N3
A_2   0     0
A_1   0     0
A_3   1     0
A_4   2     0
A_6   1     0
A_5   3     0
NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can rewrite `col2` with values from `col1` when they exist in `col2`:

```
df.col2 = df.col1[df.col1.isin(df.col2)]
```

Result:

```
df
Out[13]: 
  col2 col1
0  A_2  A_2
1  A_1  A_1
2  A_3  A_3
3  A_4  A_4
4  A_6  A_6
5  A_5  A_5
6  NaN  A_8
7  NaN  A_7
```

---

**Edit**: expanded question with two dataframes

This implicitly assumes that the values in `df2.N1` are unique (except for `NaN` values). We can therefore use them as an index to get the corresponding values from `N2` and `N3`. We can then use `df1.col1` as index values:

```
In[53] : df2.set_index('N1', drop=False).loc[df1.col1]
Out[53]: 
      N1   N2   N3
N1                
A_2  A_2    0    0
A_1  A_1    0    0
A_3  A_3    1    0
A_4  A_4    2    0
A_6  A_6    1    0
A_5  A_5    3    0
A_8  NaN  NaN  NaN
A_7  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

You can always add `.reset_index(drop=True)` to reset the index.

Comment: is there a way to generalize this to sorting an entire dataframe by a column in another dataframe?

Comment: Give me an example (for instance by adding it to your original question) and I'll give you an answer :)

Comment: @atomsmasher (just to be sure you are notified)